# Screen Resolution: xrandr "cannot find mode"

Tags: 10.04, xorg

So I do a vanilla install of 10.04 Lucid Lynx, and login. The display resolution is clearly smaller than it should be.

I did a quick Google search, and then run `xrandr`:
`Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1360x768       59.8

   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2

   848x480        60.0

   640x480        59.9     59.9`

Looks great- all I have to do is add a higher mode, 1360X1020. So I run `cvt 1360 1020` and get this:
`# 1360x1020 59.99 Hz (CVT 1.39M3) hsync: 63.47 kHz; pclk: 114.75 MHz
Modeline "1360x1020_60.00"  114.75  1360 1448 1584 1808  1020 1023 1027 1058 -hsync +vsync`

Alright. I copy the modeline, run `xrandr --newmode` with the modeline that I have, and there's no errors. However, here's the problem. When I try to use the new resolution, this is what happens:

$ `xrandr --addmode VGA1 1360X1020_60.00

xrandr: cannot find mode "1360X1020_60.00"`

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error, because I seem to have done all of the steps right. If it helps, the monitor is an Acer AL1714 running on a Dell Optiplex GX520. Thanks for any assistance in advance.
`

Comment: You seem to have typed a small "x" in the modeline (`1360x1020`), but a capital "X" in `xrandr --addmode`.  Is this just a copy/paste error?

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much, I've been trying to fix this for days! Post it as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Exactly same issue! your question helped me solve it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> You seem to have typed a small "x" in the modeline (1360x1020), but a capital "X" in `xrandr --addmode`
>       – [Riccardo Murri](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13254/screen-resolution-xrandr-cannot-find-mode#comment13756_13254)

Answer (score 9):

Running the command

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1360x1020
```

would have done just as well.

`xrandr` (without arguments) will list the existing modes and the ones that can be added.